# How to show thumbnail of a asp.net website on facebook?

Tags: asp.net, html, facebook, c#-4.0, azure

I developed a Asp.net website that play youtube videos on one page. I hosted it in windows Azure recently. But if I took a url of a page which play video and post it on facebook then facebook doesn't show any thumbnail. Can any one help me pls ?

to understand my needs you can post both of the following urls to facebook.

http://hiruvideos.hirufm.lk/index.php?page=videos-watch&id=1705

http://mostamazingvideos.azurewebsites.net/PlayVideos.aspx?uid=1

Second one doesn't show any thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the Facebook Open Graph meta tags that tell Facebook what image to show when somebody shares the link to your website. Follow the best practices at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices (Section 3 talks about the meta tags).